# Trying to find sample (eclipse project) for GWT / App Engine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, jdo, datastore, objectify

Someone must know of a working eclipse project for   GWT  / App Engine datastore ?

I tried to find a completed sample for  the stockwatcher with JDO tutorial, but
no luck.

I found 2 Objectify samples: listwidget  (checkout failed)
and gwt-objectify-appengine (Maven build failed, complained 
about missing appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.1.jar, which was actually present).

Ideally I'm looking for something minimal, an RPC app that will deploy to App Engine & save/reload a few values.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [GWT downloads](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/list) page on google-code, you can find the code for the tutorial application StockWatcher. [This](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/detail?name=Tutorial-GettingStartedAppEngine-2.1.zip&can=2&q=) zip is the StockWatcher app configured for Google App Engine. It does not use Maven. Please have a look at the README.txt file in the zip file for detailed instructions on how to import the project in Eclipse.

It is the code that lets you start [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine) from step 3.

Comment: People say this tutorial takes about 2 days to complete & then the program fails to run as described. All I want to do is save a couple of integers. Surely there must be an easier way?

Comment: If these people say so ... This is a very basic tutorial, that takes no more than 1-2 hours to complete fully. It is well documented and shows you how to use JDO, which is what you're looking for. I've completed it personnally, all you have to do is read it and copy/paste the code samples.

Comment: OK I'll take your word that its a good tutorial. But I'm wondering if I should use Objectify.

Comment: I can't say about objectify sorry, I've never used it

Comment: OK I think I'll go with http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify, but your answer is technically correct

Answer (score 0):

GWT's own [MobileWebApp](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/mobilewebapp/) is one such sample project. It's mavenized so to make it an Eclipse project simply check it out as a Maven project in Eclipse (assuming you have [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) installed).

Comment: Maven project doesn't build. I rarely find 1 that does. Lots of deceptive messages about missing jars that are not missing, missing SDKs etc. I thought Maven is supposed to make things easier?